# Pass dropdownlist value from View to Controller in Asp.Net MVC4 without using jquery or javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im new to Asp.Net MVC 4 and my question is

Is it possible to send dropdown list value from View to Controller without using jquery or javascript.
I'm always getting the value of `Department` as `null`

My Model is as follows

```
 public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

My controller is as follows

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Employee modelEmployee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Employees.Add(modelEmployee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }            
        return View(modelEmployee);
    }
```

My View is as follows

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Department,new SelectList(Model.Department,"Id","Name",
Model.DepartmentId),"Select Department")
```

Comment: You cant bind a select (or any other control) to a complex object. Bind to proeprty `DepartmentId`, but your not creating a `SelectList` anyway (Model.Department is a single object, not a collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ViewBag to create the select items in your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
    CreateDepartmentsDropdown();
    return View(employee);
}

private void CreateDepartmentsDropdown()
{
    ViewBag.Departments = db
        .Departments
        .ToList()
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.Name,
            Value = c.Id.ToString()
        });
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Departments,
                                "-- Select department --")
```

Comment: Arrh. Use strongly typed helpers as OP has done! Setting the `Selected` property is pointless (the selected option is the value of property `DepartmentId`) and it can simply be `ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(db.Departments, "ID", "Name");`

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems already solved, yet as simpler it is the mistake of passing the same collection property that binds to dropdown rather passing the type of property to hold the selected data.

@devqon provided the solution using the normal html helper yet it can be achieved through the strongly typed helper too.

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Department,new SelectList(Model.Department,"Id","Name", Model.DepartmentId),"Select Department")`

Replace the above code as,

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.DepartmentId,new SelectList(Model.Department,"Id","Name", Model.DepartmentId),"Select Department")`